# null reference when adding dictionary in unity3d

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am adding a text file in dictionary but it is giving error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
original File

aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
```

Code:

```
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.Linq;

var MytextAsset:TextAsset;
var myDictionary :Dictionary.<String,String>;
function Start () {

    /* split the text file up by newline characters */

    var textLines : String [] = MytextAsset.text.Split("/rn"[0]);  
    myDictionary.Add(textLines[0], textLines[0]);

}
```

the error is in last line..

Comment: I'm not sure that this is C#.

Comment: Feel free to retag, I just guessed.

Comment: The code is familiar, but C# does not use colons like that. I don't know what that is.

Comment: I've tagged with unity3d as well - hopefully someone can edit it with the correct tag/s.

Comment: What is the file extension of your code file?

Comment: file extension of my code file is .js

Comment: I added my answer below with a little extra looping to get your file into the dictionary properly.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure if you are really using C# here, you most likely need to initialize the `myDictionary` with a new instance of `Dictionary.<String,String>`. Try something like

```
var myDictionary :Dictionary.<String,String> = new Dictionary.<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to instantiate your dictionary before using it, do this in your start before you use Add() and you should be plain sailing. Here is a working example I just ran in unity using your file example. I just edited to also add in the loop you need to add all the lines into the `myDictionary` object:

```
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.Linq;

var MytextAsset:TextAsset;
var myDictionary :Dictionary.<String,String>;
function Start () {

     /* split the text file up by newline characters */

    var textLines : String [] = MytextAsset.text.Split("\n"[0]);  
    myDictionary = new Dictionary.< String, String >() ;
    for(index = 0 ; index < textLines.length ; ++index){
        myDictionary.Add(textLines[index],textLines[index]);
    }

    for(index = 0 ; index < myDictionary.Count; ++index){
        Debug.Log(myDictionary.Item[textLines[index]]);
    }
}
```

[image: Example2]

Comment: thanku soo much for the help now it is adding the values but when i want to access any value through key it give error key not found

Comment: That depends on what you are using to set the key. As your original code reflects your key is equal to the value, which is a bit redundant. How are you wanting to access the value? What type of key do you want to use?

Comment: i want to use the word in the list as the key so that when we search for the word it tells weather it is valid or not

Comment: If that is the case why not just store them in a list or array instead and simply return true if the string is found?